# Spring security not awares of spring mvc's view prefix

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a simple `spring mvc + spring security` app

I declare when user try `.../hello` the `hello.jsp` page from `/WEB-INF/pages/` path displays correctly:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello")
public ModelAndView doLogin() {
    return new ModelAndView("hello");
}
```

`dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

And now i declare in spring security that when user wants `.../hello` it **must** be a user.

But when i try the `http://localhost:8080/hello/` the `hello.jsp` page displays with out forcing to authentication.

When i try `http://localhost:8080/pages/hello.jsp` it redirect me to `login` page, but why spring security don't notice the `prefix path` of spring mvc?

**UPDATE**

`security-config.xml`

```
<security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/hello.jsp" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:user-service>
            <security:user name="sajjad" authorities="ROLE_USER" password="200200"/>
        </security:user-service>
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

When i use `pattern="/hello"` and user try `http://localhost:8080/hello/` the user not redirects to `login` page.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `intercept-url pattern` to `pattern="/hello/"` and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this from

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/hello.jsp" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

to

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/pages/hello*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

In your intercept configuration you specifically asked to checked only hello.jsp and not hello. Spring Security will not automatically change logic based on your view resolver.

Comment: Since the browser automatically add an extra `/` at the end of the url, i add a `/` and the end of the pattern and removed the `/pages/` from url.